# return nsmutablearray from twitter account block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, twitter-oauth, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to make a function which returns a list of twitter users but I am not able to make the function return a nsmutablearray. Here it is the code I execute

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getTwitterUsersInPosition: (Position*) position
```

{
    // Request access to the Twitter accounts

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
    if (granted) {

        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account

        if (accounts.count > 0)
        {
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];

            // Creating a request to get the info about a user on Twitter

                           NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"geocode", @"count", nil];
            NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"37.781157,-122.398720,100mi", @"2", nil];
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects
                                                                   forKeys:keys];

            SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"] parameters:dictionary];
            [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

            // Making the request

            [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler: ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    // Check if we reached the rate limit

                    if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                        NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                        return;
                    }

                    // Check if there was an error

                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Check if there is some response data

                    if (responseData) {

                        NSError *error = nil;
                        NSArray *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                        NSMutableArray *usersArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                        NSMutableArray* statuses= [(NSDictionary *) TWData objectForKey:@"statuses"];

                        for (NSDictionary* dict in statuses )
                        {
                            NSString* user = [[dict objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
                            NSLog(@"%@",user);
                            [usersArray addObject:user];
                        }
                         return userArray; //Here it says "Return type 'NSMutabelArray *' must match previous type 'void' when block literal has unspecified return type


                    }

                });


            }];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No access granted");
    }
}];
```

}

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your method can NOT have a return type because the value you want to return is obtained asynchronously and isn't available until after the method has completed.

You need to rewrite your method so that it returns the data:

1. To a delegate
2. Via a block
3. Into an instance variable and triggers some update
4. Via a notification

Basically some mechanism that allows you to deal with the asynchronous response. Please don't make the call synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you show me how can I do that via a notification?

Comment: You could do something like:  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didReceiveTwitterUsers" object:userArray] and observe the notification where you require the user information

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of your code you simply write `return` without a value (as if your method has return type of `void`):

```
if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
    NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
    return;
}

// Check if there was an error

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    return;
```

Change it to `return nil` and the code should compile.

Comment: the code compiles with "return", I think that the problem is below when I try to return a NSMutableArray